# How to convert Blob xml to doc in Angular2+

Tags: java, angular, spring, typescript, spring-boot

I get response from back-end (java) in xml format successfully and I downloaded but when I try to open it I get invalid Input/Output error.

//this is method from my service

```
getDoc(){
   return this.http.get("http://localhost:17080/files/doc",{responseType: 
'text'});
  }
```

//this is my method in .ts file

```
openDoc(){
    this.dataService.getDoc().subscribe((response)=>{
      console.log(response);
      let blob = new Blob([response],  { type: 
'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' 
});

      fs.saveAs(blob, "name.doc");
  }
```

//and this is method from my back-end

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doc", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public byte[] getDoc(){ 
        return readFile("somelink");
    }
```

//readFile method

```
private byte[] readFile(String url) {

        BufferedInputStream bis = null;

        try {
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(new URL(url).openStream());
            byte[] dataToReturn = new byte[ARRAY_SIZE];
            bis.read(dataToReturn, 0, ARRAY_SIZE);
            return dataToReturn;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        } finally {
            if(bis != null) {
                try {
                    bis.close();
                } catch (IOException e){
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                     e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Please edit and expand your question, rather than adding comments. You can then better format code and make it much more readable.

Comment: @Stein Thank you for response, I am new to this forum, I will expand my question in future and make more readable questions.